# Push Notification using RHMAP

Tags: push-notification, rhmap, feedhenry

I am trying to send push notification using RHMAP to iOS devices. Can anyone please let me know how to send push notification to specific device ID using RHMAP. I am able to send notification to all the devices but not to a specific device. 
I couldn't find anything regarding this in RHMAP documentation also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RHMAP has a lot of documented material and examples about push notifications.

The information that you are looking for is in the section "2.3.4.2. Recipient filtering"[1] of the Product features documentation.

"alias - user identification, such as a user name or an e-mail representing a single person (with possibly multiple devices). Intended to enable a unicast communication model."

For more information and examples you can check to fh.push client API[2] and fh.push cloud API[3]. There you can find the following example with filter criteria in the push notifications.

```
Push a message for specific deviceType in a specific Client App

var message = {
  alert: "hello from FH"
},
  options = {
    apps: ["3uzl1ebi6utciy56majgqlj8"], // list of App IDs
    criteria: {
      deviceType: "android"
    }
  };
$fh.push(message, options,
  function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    } else {
      console.log("status : " + res.status);
    }
  });
```

In the example above, for you implement your method using alias, you need to change the deviceType for alias as the following example.

```
alias: [] // Set here the alias that you are looking for
```

The following is an example for Android.

```
import com.feedhenry.sdk.PushConfig;
..........
......
...

    private void register() {

        PushConfig p = new PushConfig();
        p.setAlias("my-alias");

        FH.pushRegister(p, new FHActCallback() {
            @Override
            public void success(FHResponse fhResponse) {
                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MessagesActivity.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void fail(FHResponse fhResponse) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        fhResponse.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
```

[1] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_mobile_application_platform_hosted/3/html-single/product_features/#sending-notifications

[2] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_mobile_application_platform_hosted/3/html-single/client_api/#fh-push

[3] - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_mobile_application_platform_hosted/3/html-single/cloud_api/#fh-push

Answer (score 1):

You can set an alias for the device and use that alias to send the notification to it.

As you don't mention which SDK (Objective-C, Swift, Cordova) are you using I can't help you on how to set the alias as it's different for each of them, if you provide more information I can try to help you.